# Magento Import using Google Docs

Tags: import, google-api

How would you approach this? 
The scenario I am looking at is:

- a user creates/makes some changes to a Google Docs Spreadsheet (in a format quite similar to the one needed by Magento)
- a script takes this Spreadsheet and performs a validation (columns are valid, attribute values are valid, sku exist and so on)
- if the Spreadsheet is valid for import, additional processing takes place to make it compatible with Magento's Import format (not DataFlow); Magento's import format for attributes with multiple values is not that friendly from a user perspective
- then this Spreadsheet can be imported in Magento.

Are there some extensions that already do this? Other people that have done this, share your experience. Additional things to consider?

Comment: Did you consider using Magmi? it works wonders and you can call it via a script using this plugin http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Import_Url_UI

Comment: Heh, I remember when [this was a Developer Challenge back in 2008](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/announcing-magento-developers-challenge/) :-)

Answer (score 5):

[Ashley Schroder](https://twitter.com/aschroder) has written a [Google Docs/Drive adapter](http://www.aschroder.com/2012/09/improving-magento-importexport-module-with-better-file-format-and-google-docs-integration/) for the ImportExport module. It's not dataflow and it's fast!

If you really want to do additional processing before doing an import, you may consider using an array-based ImportExport extension such as [ApiImport.](https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport) An added benefit is that it takes care of a bunch of stuff for you (such as indexing). In that case you would have to write the glue between fetching google docs CVS, converting it to an appropriate format, and doing the import.

Comment: Nice!  Curious - does Google Spreadsheets API expose an updated_at date per each row in the spreadsheet and can you query on it to be able to only pull in fresh updates since the last sync/import?

Answer (score 0):

I was coming to this post, because I also searched something. In Magento 2 I am using that extension "Spreadsheet Product Master"

It helped me a lot. You have even that functionality you mentioned "if the Spreadsheet is valid for import". It will give you a feedback if the data was wrongly inserted e.g. if you forgot to insert a price.